# C++ cmake Project Structure with modular libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, structure, libraries

I have been searching a lot but I can't seem to find good and consistent info on how to make a CMAKE C++ project highly modular.

**Info about project:**

- C++ CMAKE project that creates an executable (not a library).
- I want various parts of the project to be libraries so they can be potentially used by other projects.
- Let's say this project depends on 3 libraries. Let's call them *TheLib*, *SubLib1*, *SubLib2*. I want SubLib1 and SubLib2 to be independent, meaning that someone can use them alone. But TheLib depends on the two sub-libs. Also I should note that these 3 libraries are developed by me, but I want to allow anyone (or future-me) to just pick any of these 3 and include them in another project.
- I want these 3 libraries to be included in the project, and *not* be expected to be found somewhere else.
- The project also depends on a third-party lib, let's call it *ExtLib*. I also want this library to be included in the project and not be expected to be found somewhere else.
- The different libraries should have their own CMakeLists.txt

**What I want to do:**

Find a project structure that communicates the architecture of the project.

**What would it look like, if I had to guess:**

```
project_root/
-CMakeLists.txt (the main cmake file)
-thirdparty/
---ExtLib/ (contains include/, src/, CMakeLists.txt)
-src/
---Main.cpp
---depends/
-----TheLib/
-------CMakeLists.txt (cmake file for TheLib)
-------include/
---------TheLib/
-----------TheLib.h
-------src/
---------TheLib.cpp
---------depends/
-----------SubLib1/ (contains include/, src/, CMakeLists.txt)
-----------SubLib2/ (contains include/, src/, CMakeLists.txt)
```

**Questions: (I know they are a lot, any help on any of them would be appreciated)**

- What do you think of the structure as a whole?
- Should the code for the libraries be outside of the root's src directory?
- I have seen some projects that have CMakeLists.txt inside the src (and not at the program's/library's root). Is there a difference?
- I have seen some projects that have very simple CMakeLists.txt files for the libraries. Is that how it is supposed to be? Let's say SubLib1 depends on ReallyExtLib, that is supposed to not be included in the code and be in /opt/local/include or something similar). Should the CMakeLists.txt of SubLib1 have find_package( ReallyExtLib) etc? (I am assuming no and just include it in the project's root CMakeLists.txt)
- Excluding the thirdparty dependency, do you have any examples of what the CMakeLists.txt for project, TheLib, SubLibX should look like? I have found [this link](http://techminded.net/blog/modular-c-projects-with-cmake.html), but it seems to be about building a library not an executable.

Thank you.

Comment: libraries or executable, it's basically the same. Don't put your sublibraries like that, usually source and includes are int he same folder in lots of projects, sometimes not, but sub libraries, are like the main library on the same level as the executable. But it's primarily opinion based. Have a look at my structure (I have mainly libraries, but also executables): https://github.com/mbrucher/AudioTK The main organization is not about the source code, but how your set up your CMake support files and functions.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I understand your point about putting "TheLib" in the root directory. But Since "TheLib" needs "SubLib1" and "SubLib2" to work (and remember I want "TheLib" to be modular itself) wouldn't it make sense to at least put the sub-libs inside the /root/TheLib/ directory?

Comment: It may. But perhaps you will add another library one day that uses SubLib1, but not TheLib? But it's very opinion based, anything can work.